# SoapUI uses mesagename and not operationname in message

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui

I have a problem with a service wsdl that is delivered by a third party. Let my try to explain. Take this wsdl part:

```
<wsdl:portType name="IBestelService">
      <wsdl:operation name="PlaatsOrder">
         <wsdl:input message="tns:PlaatsOrderRequest"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:PlaatsOrderResponse"/>
         <wsdl:fault message="tns:BestelServiceFault" name="BestelServiceFault"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
      <wsdl:operation name="PlaatsOrderThreeShips">
         <wsdl:input message="tns:PlaatsOrderRequestThreeShips"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:PlaatsOrderResponseThreeShips"/>
         <wsdl:fault message="tns:BestelServiceFault" name="BestelServiceFault"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
```

For the request soapui (and .net to) generates the following request:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sambo-ict:basetypes:1.0" xmlns:urn1="urn:sambo-ict:bestelservice:types:1.0">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:AuthenticationHeader xmlns="urn:sambo-ict:basetypes:1.0"/>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn1:PlaatsOrderRequest>
         <EAN>9789490998394</EAN>
         <DistributorOrderId>13188</DistributorOrderId>
         <DeliveryMethod>Tegoed</DeliveryMethod>
         <Amount>1</Amount>
      </urn1:PlaatsOrderRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However the service at the third party site expects this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:sambo-ict:basetypes:1.0" xmlns:urn1="urn:sambo-ict:bestelservice:types:1.0">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:AuthenticationHeader xmlns="urn:sambo-ict:basetypes:1.0"/>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn1:PlaatsOrder>
         <EAN>9789490998394</EAN>
         <DistributorOrderId>13188</DistributorOrderId>
         <DeliveryMethod>Tegoed</DeliveryMethod>
         <Amount>1</Amount>
      </urn1:PlaatsOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I search the internet on soap. The "plaatsorder" instead of "plaatsorderrequest" seems to be the right way. However I do not believe that both soapui/java and .net have it wrong. So can anyone explain the difference to me?

Comment: Can you please post the whole WSDL with any associated schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element:

```
<wsdl:input message="tns:PlaatsOrderRequest"/>
```

will have an associated message entry that looks like:

```
<wsdl:message name="PlaatsOrderRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="urn1:PlaatsOrderRequest" name="parameters" />
</wsdl:message>
```

That element name is what dictates the wrapped request element, assuming this is a document/literal wrapped service (which they usually are).  I would need the full WSDL and schema to be more definitive.

Comment: I corrected a local copy of the third party wsdl and you answer was correct, knowing what to look for I found http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-usagewsdl/ that references the rules for this. I put out a request to third party to correct the wdsl to bring it in line with expected request format

Answer (score 0):

You can make this change by yourself in wsdl. It's easy just replace that tag whichever is required. It would work.
by the way you can directly ask your client by providing right wsdl with this change. It would be easy for them to generate wsdl with required request tag.